# Hazelcast Jet MultiMap source support?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I couldn't find any possibilities to construct Source from MultiMap,
why such Source is not provided in standard API?
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2/manual/#overview-of-sources-and-sinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's (currently, in Jet 3.2) no `Source.multimap()`, Jet provides a way to create your own custom Sources and Sinks via a Builder API.

Please check the relevant documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2/manual/#source-sink-builder